# Java embedded database persistence

Tags: java, database, embedded-database

When using embedded java databases, can someone explain how the database persists data across sessions? Does it create a local file on the PC that is reloaded when the app connects to the database? Or would I need to explicitly dump/reload the contents on exist/restart?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is performed automatically. The database stored its information into the filesystem for you.

Here's more information: [Java DB FAQ](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/features/faqs.jsp) which is the most common embedded db.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they create a file on the filesystem - you don't have to take extra steps to ensure your data is persistent between sessions.